# Some Apache configuration issues

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd, php, xampp

I have been playing around with my Apache [config file](https://pastebin.com/HFJYXHU0)  for a while to get WSGI working for my Flask application.

I was not able to get `phpMyAdmin` working though (`localhost/phpmyadmin` shows the `php` code), so I thought I'd try XAMPP. I installed it and was able to get `phpMyAdmin` working. However, I couldn't get it to work with WSGI. So, I removed `/opt/lampp`. But now, even if my `httpd.service` is not running and `localhost` "refuses to conect", `localhost/phpMyAdmin` prompts a Download in my browser which downloads [this code](https://pastebin.com/JXnCMFBs), and `localhost/phpmyadmin/setup` returns [this code](https://pastebin.com/ktucqJiN).

One more thing, `localhost/phpmyadmin` showed the XAMPP favicon in the title bar. So I deleted `usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin/favicon.ico` (which I checked, and it looked exactly like that). But now, though `localhost/phpmyadmin` doesn't show that icon, `localhost/phpmyadmin/setup` still does.

My questions:

1. How to get PHP to work in Apache? (Trust me, I have read every guide on the Internet)
2. How am I able to access `localhost/phpmyadmin` if `httpd` is not running?

Thanks!!

PS: I am on Arch, btw.

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once.

Comment: "_I have read every guide on the Internet_" I highly doubt that

Comment: @roaima ...figure of speech...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, clean up everything relevant including packages, as you seem to have no idea where you are. Then start with simple Apache. Is it working fine? Learn making small (tiny) modifications in the config and checking if they work. Once you're fine with the basics, reach for the PHP mod for the same Apache and see what can be done with that. Once you're ok with the mod and still can remember the basics, you should have no problems getting stuff depending on these work, troubleshooting include. Before you get there, don't ruin your learning with installing things, which will make it hard for you to find out, what's going on with your HTTP interface like other HTTP servers. And once you've come to terms with PHP under Apache, you can move to WSGI, Ruby or whatever.